# Wordcloud update data/ working example of adding words to cloud?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, updating, word-cloud

I am still pretty new to d3.js and I am diving into a wordcloud example using the 
d3-cloud repo : https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud

The example which is in there works for me, I turned it into a function so I can call it when data updates:

```
  wordCloud : function(parameters,elementid){

        var p = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(parameters));
        var fill = d3.scale.category20(); 

        if (d3.select(elementid).selectAll("svg")[0][0] == undefined){
            var svg = d3.select(elementid).append("svg")
                    .attr("width", 500)
                    .attr("height", 500)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(300,300)");        
        }else var svg =  d3.select(elementid).selectAll("svg")
                .attr("width", 500)
                .attr("height", 500)
                .select("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(300,300)");


        d3.layout.cloud().size([300, 300])
                .words(p.data)
                .padding(5)
                .rotate(function(d) {return ~~(Math.random()) *  p.cloud.maxrotation; })
                .font("Impact")
                .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
                .on("end", draw)
                .start();

        function draw(words) {
            console.log(words)
            console.log(words.length)
            svg.selectAll("text")
                    .data(words)
                    .enter().append("text")
                    .style("font-size", function(d) {return d.size + "px"; })
                    .style("font-family", "Impact")
                    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text(function(d) {console.log("enter text " + d.text) ; return d.text; });

            svg.selectAll("text")
                    .data(words).transition().duration(2000).attr("transform", function(d) {
                        return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + Math.random() *  p.cloud.maxrotation + ")";
            })

        } 
    }
```

The code works for me. 
element id = the elements you bind to
parameters = all parameters which i should be able to set, including data (parameters.data).

Except for the packaging the code wasn't altered much from the original:
https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/examples/simple.html

However when I add a new word to the wordcloud (so when I update the data), the new word is not recognized. I have put log output on several places and apparently in the draw function the data is incorrect but before it is ok.

for example:
original: `[{"text":"this","size":5},{"text":"is","size":10},{"text":"a","size":50},{"text":"sentence","size":15}]`
(the code adds other properties but this is for simplicity of explanation)

I add: "testing" with a size of 5

correct would be

```
[{"text":"this","size":5},{"text":"is","size":10},{"text":"a","size":50},{"text":"sentence","size":15},{"text":"testing","size":5}]
```

but I get results like:

```
[{"text":"a","size":50},{"text":"testing","size":5},{"text":"this","size":5},{"text":"sentence","size":15}]
```

--> new word added , an older one removed (don't know why) and array was mixed up.

QUESTION:

1. Anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong?

or

2. Does anybody have a working example of a d3.js wordcloud which you can update with new words by means of lets say an input box?

Answer (score 0):

I think u got the same problem with me. The size of all the words do not fit in your svg and d3.layout.cloud somehow remove the oversized word. Try to increase the width and height of your svg or decrease the size of your word. What I done is check whether the x,y,width and height of the word is it out of the box. If yes, decrease the size or increase the width and height. Correct me if i am wrong